# Terraria Moving on to hardmode

Tags: terraria

In Terraria I'm thinking of entering Hardmode but I never feel confident enough or I haven't explored much of my world. I've got full molten armour and I need just the blade of grass to craft the Nights edge. What should I do in defense wise?
For example, I don't want my jungle corrupted like I want my home/base invaded by monsters all the time. What should I do to protect it like lock it down?

Answer (score 0):

For your jungle, surround it with the Hallow, which can be purchased as seeds from the Dryad. You should also surround any important areas with Hallow to prevent the spread of Crimson and Corruption (Yes, they both appear). You should also find as many Demon alters as possible, because you'll need to break them in order to get the new ores. Hardcore is one of the best parts of the game, and if you're prepared, the most fun.

Answer (score 0):

Before entering Hardmode, you can cut 3 block wide tunnels around your existing corruption to at least control it's spread.  Some folks also cut 3 block wide firewall tunnels through their world to contain outbreaks of corruption/hallow seeded by smashed altars.

Above Altitude 0, you will also have to control the growth of thorn bushes.  Bricks, Clay & sod removal are all viable tools for this.

I generally assume that my town will get infected.  As such I plant Hallow around it to make sure it's the right kind of infection.